# Excel VBA INDEX MATCH (not pasting a formula using the code)

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I've seen several questions asked around using `INDEX MATCH` on multiple criteria within VBA, but they all seem to revolve around pasting a formula into a cell.

I'm looping thru a `ListObject` and trying to do a lookup on 3 criteria on a diff sheet, but I want the value pasted into the cell not the formula. I've tried using various combos of `Application.Index`, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index`, `Application.Match`, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and `Evaluate()` but I'm still getting `#Value!` (when I don't get a an Error). Some of what I've tried below (it's prob a very simple mistake I'm making).

`wsSrc` has the following ranges as part of a `ListObject` and I want to paste the result onto `wsDest`.

```
rngDate = Range("Table24[date]") 'Date
rngFrom = Range("Table24[from]") 'String
rngTo = Range("Table24[to]") 'String

rngLookup = Range("Table24[lookup]") 'Double
```

Based on a combination of a Date, From and To I want to lookup a value in `rngLookup`.

I've tried:

```
Application.Index(rngLookup.Address, _
Application.Match(strDate & "USD" & strTo, _
rngDate.Address & rngFrom.Address & rngTo.Address))
```

I've also tried:

```
x = wsSrc.Evaluate("INDEX(" & rngLookup.Address & _
",MATCH(" & strDate & "USD" & strTo & "," & _
rngDate.Address & "&" & rngFrom.Address & "&" & rngTo.Address)
```

I've even tried converting the date using `CStr(CDate())` which works on in Excel, but not in the VBA.

No joy on either, any thoughts? Again, to confirm I want just the value not the formula pasted into a cell.

Comment: `rngDate = Range("Table24[date]") 'Date` puts the value in as array variable, that variable is not a range type variable, so it does not have `.Address` as a child.

Comment: Have you declared `rngDate` (etc) `As Range` or `As Date`/`As String`.  If they are `Range` objects, you should `Set rngDate = ...`.  (If you have declared them as base data types, or allowed them to default to be `Variant`, then as Scott says you have just put the values into an array, which therefore won't have an `Address` property.)  It would really help us help you if you showed enough code that we could replicate your issue without having to guess about your declarations.

Comment: Index/Match is a worksheet solution, and not the best one for your problem. When you employ VBA you would look for the date using `Find` and then check the 'To' and 'From' columns for a match, looping until found. This wouldn't need the `lookup` range. However, if you wish to provide that range a simple `Find` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using a table and columns of the same name:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, dt, sFrom, sTo

Set sht = ActiveSheet  ' e.g.
dt = DateSerial(2017, 12, 18)
sFrom = "B"
sTo = "C"

Debug.Print sht.Evaluate( _
       "INDEX(Table24[lookup],MATCH(1," & _
       "(Table24[date]=" & (dt * 1) & ")*" & _
       "(Table24[from]=""" & sFrom & """)*" & _
       "(Table24[to]=""" & sTo & """),0))")
```

Assumes your table's dates are actual dates and not strings.